BLDC DR8305 design 42A
I'm trying to design my own PCB to control 4 x 300W three-phase motors with the DRV8305 BLDC and an STM32F401, but I have a problem with the number of PWMs available.
To solve the problem of the number of PWMs I use the PCA9685PW component which can generate up to 16 independent PWMs but I need 12 ADCs for SO1 SO2 and SO3 4 times. Is current sensing necessary or can I get this information from the SPI?
Do I need to change anything in my schematic?




Is current sensing necessary

The data sheet tells you why you might want to use current sensing: -
7.3.5.3 CSAs: Current Shunt Amplifiers
The DRV8305 includes three high performance low-side current shunt  
amplifiers for accurate current measurement utilizing low-side 
shunt resistors in the external half-bridges. They are commonly 
used to measure the motor phase current to implement overcurrent 
protection, external torque control, or external commutation
control through the application MCU.

So, if you believe you don't need to implement these things: -
They are commonly used to measure the motor phase current to implement overcurrent protection, external torque control, or external commutation
control through the application MCU.
Then you probably don't need to use current sensing.

can I get this information from the SPI?

No you can't. Look at the block diagram on page 16.

Do I need to change anything in my schematic?


C37 looks a bit sad not having both its pins connected.
I would have drawn it in a more logical fashion
I would have added power supply details
I would have added supply/bulk capacitors as per the DS recommendations
I believe SP1, SP2 and SP3 need to be connected to GND and not how you did it: -



Ok, so I need to connect SO1 SO2 and SO3 to my MCU ok. In fact I forgot to connect C37 correctly. regarding the power supply I also forgot, I updated the post if you want to have a look. where do you want to add the power supply/bulk capacitor?

Please don't update your question because it makes my answer look wrong. I shall roll back your question to how it was when I answered it.

I've connected SP1, SP2 and SP3 to GND but I don't understand where you want to put the supply/bulk capacitors.

They go between main power rail and ground and, are placed close to the MOSFETs

@Paulo971 if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
